# Nemo Custom Action (.sh script) does not execute

Tags: bash, scripts, nemo

I created a .sh script for simple OCR-ing of screenshots that I make with Shutter.
The script looks like this (`ocrFile.sh`):

```
#!/bin/bash

convert $1 /tmp/output.pnm
cat /tmp/output.pnm | pamstretch 4 > /tmp/stretched.pnm
convert /tmp/stretched.pnm -colorspace gray /tmp/output600dpi.tif
tesseract /tmp/output600dpi.tif ./outputText -l eng
```

This script does some image enhancing that is required when OCRing with tesseract.
It does the job properly if it is called from the terminal. What I wanted was to do the whole process within Nemo, so I created a custom action named `OCR.nemo_action` inside `/home/user1/.local/share/nemo/actions` with the following content:

```
[Nemo Action]
Name=OCR The Screenshoot
Comment=OCR Function for Nemo File Manager
Exec=<ocrFile.sh %F>
Icon-Name=gtk-execute
Selection=Any
Extensions=png;
```

This Nemo action don't produce output with the script given above.
The .sh script is also in the folder for Nemo's custom actions.

Please help!

Comment: It is impossible to debug, since typing 'nemo' in the terminal launches the application and returns the prompt.

Comment: The whole process works under Mint Mate. The parameter for picking up the file was only %f instead of %F.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Great!!

### -- ~/OCR.sh  ( chmod +x ~/OCR.sh )

```
#!/bin/bash
convert $1 /tmp/OCR-output.pnm
cat /tmp/OCR-output.pnm | pamstretch 4 > /tmp/OCR-stretched.pnm
convert /tmp/OCR-stretched.pnm -colorspace gray /tmp/OCR-output600dpi.tif 
tesseract /tmp/OCR-output600dpi.tif ~/Desktop/OCR-outputText -l eng 
rm /tmp/OCR-output.pnm /tmp/OCR-stretched.pnm /tmp/OCR-output600dpi.tif
```

---

### -- ~/.local/share/nemo/actions

```
[Nemo Action]
Active=true
Name=OCR picture
Comment=OCR Function for Nemo File Manager
Selection=S
Exec=/bin/bash /home/user/OCR.sh %F                 --- change "user"
Icon-Name=gtk-execute
Extensions=png;jpg;jpeg;bmp;
```

---

And OCR text is on my Desktop !!!

Answer (score 1):

I kind of came to solution for this situation in Cinnamon.
The `.nemo_action` file consists of the following content.

```
[Nemo Action]
Name=OCR The Screenshoot
Comment=OCR Function for Nemo File Manager
Selection=S
Exec=gnome-terminal --working-directory=%P -e "/media/storage/Scripts/actions/ocrFile.sh %F"
Icon-Name=gtk-execute
Extensions=png;jpg;jpeg;bmp;
Active=true
```

Having terminal launch to do the job is rather a workaround here. Everything else didn't seem to yield results.

The bash script itself remained pretty much the same, altered only for a directive to keep the terminal open until the execution of the command set.

```
#!/bin/bash
convert $1 /tmp/output.pnm
cat /tmp/output.pnm | pamstretch 4 > /tmp/stretched.pnm
convert /tmp/stretched.pnm -colorspace gray /tmp/output600dpi.tif 
tesseract /tmp/output600dpi.tif ./outputText -l eng 
rm /tmp/output.pnm /tmp/stretched.pnm /tmp/output600dpi.tif
bash
```

What I crave ultimately is to make this process completely terminal-free. It seems to me that the process goes slightly differently from Gnome2 (Mate). Here the bash script which consists of **terminal commands** do not execute "somewhere in the background". With bash scripts that call GUI applications Gnome3's `Exec=` directive allows the `<script.sh %F>` value.

Answer (score 0):

Is it a bash script? Try

```
Exec=/bin/bash /home/user1/.local/share/nemo/actionsocrFile.sh %F
```

(or even `/bin/sh` which is usually `dash` might be slightly faster.)

As for debugging, at the command line:

```
$ nemo -q # quit all instances of nemo
$ NEMO_ACTION_VERBOSE=1 nemo
```

Then run the action from the nemo window that will have opened up.